Getting error while trying to connect SFTP using UTL_TCP package in Oracle Cloud autonomous Database
I am trying to conenct the SFTP server usign UTL_TCP package. Please find below my code. I have configured the ACL and added the CONNECT privilage as well. I am trying it in ADMIN user only
declare
    c  utl_tcp.connection;
    ret_val varchar2(100);
    reading varchar2(100);
    cmd varchar2(100) := 'COMMAND(STUFF,SERVICE,EXPECTS)';
    cmd2 varchar2(100);
begin
    c := utl_tcp.open_connection(remote_host => 'sftp.greystar.com'
                               ,remote_port =>  9995
                               ,charset     => 'US7ASCII'
                               ,tx_timeout  => 10
                               );
    ret_val := utl_tcp.write_line(c, cmd);
    ret_val := utl_tcp.write_line(c);
  
    dbms_output.put_line(utl_tcp.get_text(c, 100));  
    sys.dbms_session.sleep(1);
    cmd2 := 'POLL(' || ret_val || ')';
    reading := utl_tcp.write_line(c, cmd2);
    reading := utl_tcp.write_line(c);
    dbms_output.put_line(utl_tcp.get_text(c, 100));
    utl_tcp.close_connection(c);  --Close the connection
END;

But I am getting the below error.
Error report - ORA-01031: insufficient privileges ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_TCP", line 19 ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_TCP", line 310 ORA-06512: at line 8 01031. 00000 - "insufficient privileges" *Cause: An attempt was made to perform a database operation without the necessary privileges. *Action: Ask your database administrator or designated security administrator to grant you the necessary privileges
I tried to connect the SFTP server from Oracle ATP database. I am expecting a new file has to be created in the SFTP server.
